# Treatment of backslashes across shells

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, quoting

How do `echo` and `printf` treat backslashes in `zsh`, `bash` and other shells?

Under **zsh** I get the following behavior:

```
$ echo "foo\bar\baz"
foaaz
$ echo "foo\\bar\\baz"
foaaz
$ echo 'foo\bar\baz'
foaaz
$ echo 'foo\\bar\\baz'
foo\bar\baz
```

Under **bash**, things seem a bit more consistent:

```
bash$ echo "foo\bar\baz"
foo\bar\baz
bash$ echo 'foo\bar\baz'
foo\bar\baz
bash$
```

But more concretely: **How can I pass a string containing backslashes such as `\\foo\bar\something`** to:

- `echo`
- `printf`
- `print`

**and get exactly the same string?** (in `zsh` and `bash`)?

Here is another experiment with functions in zsh:

```
function foo
{
    echo -E '$1'
}

$ foo \\here\is\some\path
$1
```

How can I have it just print `\\here\is\some\path`?

#### Update (Note: this has now been answered in Stephane's comment)

I have tried the following in zsh 5.0.2:

```
function foo
{
    printf '$s\n' $1 
}

foo '\\some\path'
```

But this prints `$s` ?

Comment: Use `printf`, `echo` isn't portable in the regard.

Comment: you "foo" function : replace `'` with `"` , and invoke it with :  foo '\\here\is\some\path'  (otherwise the invoking shell gets a chance to interpret the '\' before they get to the function)

Comment: Your function used `'$s\n'` when it should have used `'%s\n'`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`zsh` `echo` behaves the standard way, like `bash` in UNIX mode. That is it expands `\b` to the ASCII BS character as the UNIX specification requires.

[Don't use `echo` to display arbitrary strings, use `printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/22565):

```
printf '%s\n' "$1"
```

`print -r -- "$1"` also works but is `ksh`/`zsh` specific.

`echo -E - "$1"` work with `zsh` and I believe some BSDs.

```
cat << EOF
$1
EOF
```

works in any Bourne-like shell even those from a few decades when there was no `printf` command but it spawn a new process, and is really not necessary nowadays as we now have `printf` everywhere.

And by the way, you need to escape backslashes on a shell command line as it's special to the shell (every shell but `rc`), so:

```
$ foo '\\foo\bar'
```

`foo \\foo\bar` would pass the `"\foo\bar"` string to `foo` which can't reinvent the lost backslash back.

Comment: Thanks Stephane. Oddly enough, the construction `printf '%s\n' "$var"` works for me on the command line (`zsh 5.0.2`, i.e. the latest), but not inside a function (see my update in the OP). Why?

Comment: It's `printf '%s\n'`, not `printf '$s\n'` you want. Note that you need to quote variables in other shells than `zsh` (`"$1"`, not `$1`) and the standard function definition syntax is `foo() { ...; }`, though any shell but `bash` allow `foo() any-command`, and `function foo { .... }` is the `ksh` syntax.

Comment: @Marcus, that's an answer to a different question.

Comment: Why does this not work: printf 'C:\foo\bar.xml'.This works: echo -E 'C:\foo\bar.xml' - Why do you put the dash in echo -E -?

Answer (score 2):

new answer:  read -r var

```
-r  raw input - disables interpretion of backslash escapes and line-continuation in the read data
```

and to display:

```
printf "%s" "$var"
echo "$var"
```

should work.

So for your foo function:

```
function foo
{
    read -r var
    echo -E "var is : ${var}"
}

$ foo 
\\here\is\some\path
var is : \\here\is\some\path
```

old answer below (not answering, but maybe usefull ^^)

just replace each `\` by `\\` to tell the shell "that it a literall `\` I want".
otherwise (for example in zsh, in your example) it could well be that `\b` means "1 backspace", or whatever.

you could for example use sed:

```
sed -e 's,\\,\\\\,g' < the_original > the_escaped_backslaches_version
```

(see how you also need to escape "\" there, to tell sed the same thing: "it is a literall "\" I want)  (and notice I surround it by ' ' and not " " to avoid the shell to interpret most of it too)

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned in the title: I want to avoid escaping backslashes.

Comment: oops, I'll edit ^^

Comment: Thanks! But `read -r var` seems to wait for input from  `STDIN`. What if I am passing it as an argument? (e.g. foo `\\here\is\some\path`)

Comment: the shell IS interpreting backslashes. That's why you should probably move the argument passing to a read, see my "foo" example.

Comment: I see, so I take that there is no way to using this using this with the syntax `foo \\here\is\some\path` in the command line?

Comment: unless you change the was the shell you're using interpret things, I guess no (but there may be a way... maybe some different "readline" settings? unfortunately, putting that way as default would break numerous habits (and probably scripts as well)...

Comment: iow: you want a "non-standard" handling of strings by the shell : you could more easily (and more extensively) have your program be compliant to what you want, instead of trying to have the shell-invoking-that-program to behave like you want. So: pass the args (the ones containing "\" that you don't want to escape) once the program is started, via "read -r", and not on its invoking shell command-line.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you can't, because backslash **is** the escape character (and as such has to be escaped when its literal value is required). BASH provides single quotes for this purpose, however you can't use escape a single quote within single quoted string.

As for the `echo` discrepancy, it is a built-in an may behave differently across shells (to some degree). For example the BASH built-in has a `-e` option which tells it to interpret backslash sequences - with it you'd get the behaviour you saw in the Z shell.